# WinForms in WPF via VS Designer?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add an ***WinForms*** UserControl into a ***WPF*** UserControl  just using VS 2010 **Designer**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the WindowsFormsHost and then include the clr-namespace and add the components :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(VS.90).aspx

You can also do it by code by adding

```
Panel p = new Panel();
WindowsFormsHost wf = new WindowsFormsHost();
wf.Child = p;
```

Comment: I would like to emphasis **Designer** I added WinForms Host, but I can't see in toolbox but WPF controls. Others are or invisible, or inactive.

Comment: It seems WPF is working a lot around XAML and then editing XAML is the best way to generate WPF GUI, designer is not really helpfull. I'm not sure you can add WF controls using the WPF GUI. You can take a look around Expression Studio, maybe Blend will be your answer :)